# Unable to install sass with ruby gem. Failing to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby, docker, sass, rubygems, bitbucket-pipelines

Trying to install sass within a bit bucket pipelines docker instance and getting the error `Failed to build gem native extension`

The logs show the following:

```
gem install sass --no-user-install
Successfully installed rb-fsevent-0.10.2
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing sass:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
```

I am using a image `php:7.1.1`

Ruby and Gem should be installed as in my script I run:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install -y unzip nodejs ruby-full
gem install sass --no-user-install
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have tried changing docker image to `atlassian/default-image:latest` to no avail

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same problem. The following packages have solved the problem:

`apt-get install -y ruby-dev gcc automake libtool rubygems build-essential`

Best regards

Comment: saved me a lot of time

Answer (score 1):

I noticed this error today too using gitlab-ci with a docker image based on php:7.0.

I tried installing `ruby-dev` and doing a `gem update --system` first as I found in another SO solution and it didn't fix the error.

Sorry i couldn't post this as a comment, my reputation is too low, but I wanted you to know you're not alone.  Hopefully this is a gem toolchain issue that gets fixed quickly.

Comment: To get around this, I ended up using a ruby image and installing the php dependencies I needed. Luckily I only needed curl and composer so wasn't too hard but if you require a lot of php dependencies, it may be a little more tricky